# How to read policies from Vault server?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

Is there any way to get vault policy details that someone has already created. It would me more easy if I could get policy details through URL, or API might make my work simpler.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ohh, I could have spend more time googling the answer instead posting this question.
I found the solution [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vault-tool/Y3H_UwAo_OE).

From the command line, to see the rules for the policy 'default', you 
would do it like this:

```
vault policies
vault policies <policy_name>
```

From the API you can do it with a `GET` to

```
/v1/sys/policy/<policy_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

To be a bit more generic, this command lists all the existing policies:

`vault policies`

and the one bellow shows the details of a specific policy:

`vault policies <policy_name>`